deep traceback calls in neural network profiling
I am working with a neural network that is supposed to recognize symmetries in images (using the MNIST dataset). Since it is implemented with PyTorch, I wanted to optimize the runtime on a GPU and used the profiler to analyze the current model. The tracing file provided by the profiler shows deep traceback calls for many operations, like this:
List of calls in the profiler in hierarchical order:

built-in method matmul of type object
aten::expand
torch/fx/traceback.py(61): format_stack
traceback.py(217): extract_stack
traceback.py(372): extract
traceback.py(394): _extract_from_extended_frame_gen
built-in function getattr
traceback.py(388): extended_frame_gen
traceback.py(331): walk_stack

The profiler is implemented as follows:
prof = profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU, ProfilerActivity.CUDA],
               profile_memory=True,
               record_shapes=True,
               with_flops=True,
               with_stack=True,
               schedule=schedule(skip_first=5, wait=5, warmup=5, active=2, repeat=1))

What could be the reasons for these deep traceback calls?
